# Disable / Enable Button in TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a button like a switch, so if I click the disable button
it will disable the "Button" (that works). And if I press it again, it will enable it again.

I tried things like if, else but didn't get it to work.
Here's an example:

```
from tkinter import *
fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Window")

def switch():
    b1["state"] = DISABLED

#--Buttons
b1=Button(fenster, text="Button")
b1.config(height = 5, width = 7)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)    

b2 = Button(text="disable", command=switch)
b2.grid(row=0,column=1)

fenster.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A Tkinter `Button` has three states : **`active, normal, disabled`**.

You set the `state` option to `disabled` to gray out the button and make it unresponsive. It has the value `active` when the mouse is over it and the default is `normal`.

Using this you can check for the state of the button and take the required action. Here is the working code.

```
from tkinter import *

fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Window")

def switch():
    if b1["state"] == "normal":
        b1["state"] = "disabled"
        b2["text"] = "enable"
    else:
        b1["state"] = "normal"
        b2["text"] = "disable"

#--Buttons
b1 = Button(fenster, text="Button", height=5, width=7)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)    

b2 = Button(text="disable", command=switch)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)

fenster.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is in your `switch` function.

```
def switch():
    b1["state"] = DISABLED
```

When you click the button, `switch` is being called each time. For a toggle behaviour, you need to tell it to switch back to the `NORMAL` state.

```
def switch():
    if b1["state"] == NORMAL:
        b1["state"] = DISABLED
    else:
        b1["state"] = NORMAL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure the states of the button as mentioned below:

```
self.true_button.config(state=DISABLED)
self.false_button.config(state=DISABLED)
```

so similarly in your program:

```
from tkinter import *
fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Window")

def switch():
    b1.config(state=DISABLED)

#--Buttons
b1=Button(fenster, text="Button")
b1.config(height = 5, width = 7)
b1.grid(row=0, column=0)    

b2 = Button(text="disable", command=switch)
b2.grid(row=0,column=1)

fenster.mainloop()
```