# Python: disable and re-enable button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

I want to create a button that I can `disable` and `re-enable` as soon as I click it. With the following code, I get a button that I can `disable`, but it won't `re-enable` when I click it. If looked at this threat, but it didn't help: [Disable / Enable Button in TKinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580507/disable-enable-button-in-tkinter/53580593)

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

# toplevel widget of Tk which represents mostly the main window of an application
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('1800x600')
root.title('Roll Dice')
frame = Frame(root)

# label to display dice
label = tkinter.Label(root, text='', font=('Helvetica', 120))

# function activated by button
def switch1():
    if button1["state"] == "active":
        button1["state"] = "disabled"
    else:
        button1["state"] = "active"

button1 = tkinter.Button(root, text='Würfel 1', foreground='green', command=lambda: switch1, state = "active")

button1.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of `"active"` use `"normal"`

Comment: Also instead of `command=lambda: switch1` use `command=switch1`. Also also you know that when the button is disabled it can't be clicked so the user can't re enable it. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to disbale and re-enable a function by clicking on the button. I guess I try it with a variable for True and False

Comment: You can add another button that toggles `button1`'s state. What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you want to toggle the button?

Comment: I want to disbale and re-enable a function by clicking on the Button.

Comment: I will try it with another button to toggle button1

Comment: You might have made a typo in the lambda statement fixing it shall yield fine results as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def toggle_state():
    if button1.cget("state") == "normal":
        button1.config(state="disabled")
    else:
        button1.config(state="normal")

root = tk.Tk()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="This button toggles state")
button1.pack()

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=toggle_state)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This uses a button to toggle the state of the other button.

Comment: If anyone is crazy and wants a oneliner ~ `command=lambda: button1.config(state="disabled") if button1.cget("state") == "normal" else button1.config(state="normal")`.

Comment: @CoolCloud Nice 1 liner. I never knew that you can put `if` statements inside `lambda`s :D

Comment: Yes, but it single handedly violated PEP8's rule of 80 characters in one line :P

Comment: @CoolCloud Also the zen of python [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Lets see how many PEPs you can violate with 1 line of code :D

Comment: thanks that works. The one liner get's me confused :D

Comment: @Mazze It is basically the same thing that I have in `toggle_state` but condensed into 1 line. Most of the time it is hard to understand/debug that is why it isn't considered good.