# tKinter switch color on hotkey click

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that opens a window and a circle at the center that is filled green at the start. I want this circle to change from red to green  and green to red each time I press a button (r in this code) however I can only change the color once

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()

    window.title("On Record")
    window.configure(width=500, height=300)
    window.configure(bg='lightgray')
    myCanvas = Canvas(window)
    myCanvas.pack()


    def daire(x, y, r, canvasName, color):  # center coordinates, radius
        x0 = x - r
        y0 = y - r
        x1 = x + r
        y1 = y + r
        return canvasName.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color)


    # move window center
    winWidth = window.winfo_reqwidth()
    winwHeight = window.winfo_reqheight()
    posRight = int(window.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - winWidth / 2)
    posDown = int(window.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - winwHeight / 2)
    window.geometry("+{}+{}".format(posRight, posDown))
    color = "green"

    def onKeyPress(event):
        print("pressed")
        counter = 0
        counter = counter + 1
        print(counter)
        if counter % 2 == 0:
            color = "green"
        else:
            color = "red"
        daire(190, 135, 120, myCanvas, color)


    window.bind("r", onKeyPress)
    daire(190, 135, 120, myCanvas, "green")
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the event function is reliant on counter being odd or even, but it auto resets it to 0 every time is is run. One solution to this is to place the counter outside of the function and call it as a global.

```
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()

    window.title("On Record")
    window.configure(width=500, height=300)
    window.configure(bg='lightgray')
    myCanvas = Canvas(window)
    myCanvas.pack()

    def daire(x, y, r, canvasName, color):  # center coordinates, radius
        x0 = x - r
        y0 = y - r
        x1 = x + r
        y1 = y + r
        return canvasName.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color)

    # move window center
    winWidth = window.winfo_reqwidth()
    winwHeight = window.winfo_reqheight()
    posRight = int(window.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - winWidth / 2)
    posDown = int(window.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - winwHeight / 2)
    window.geometry("+{}+{}".format(posRight, posDown))
    color = "green"

    counter = 0

    def onKeyPress(event):
        global counter
        print("pressed")
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
        if counter % 2 == 0:
            color = "green"
        else:
            color = "red"
        daire(190, 135, 120, myCanvas, color)


    window.bind("r", onKeyPress)
    daire(190, 135, 120, myCanvas, color)
    window.mainloop()
```

Out of interest do you actually need to be able to track how many times r is pressed? Its implied by your script but not explicitly stated. Otherwise theres more streamlined ways of doing this by referring directly to tkinter elements, as is often done with button toggles [as displayed in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53580593/12282048)