# Tkinter button acts only as a one-time switch instead of switching multiple times

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, switch-statement

this is the first question I am posting here. I recently created a window in Tkinter that contains a frame. After clicking a button a label containing text should appear inside the frame. When clicking the button again - the label should disappear. It works fine until I click the button for a third time to call the label inside the frame again.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.geometry("500x500+100+100")
root.title("Switch label")
root.resizable(False,False)

is_off=True

def label_disappear():
    global label
    global is_off

    label.destroy()
    button.config(text="Add",command=label_appear)
    is_off=True

def label_appear():
    global label
    global is_off

    if is_off:
        label.place(x=20,y=20)
        button.config(text="Remove",command=label_disappear)
        is_off=False
    else:
        label_disappear()


frame=Frame(root,bg="light green",width=460,height=200)
frame.place(x=20,y=20)


label=Label(frame,text="This is label",bg="light green")

button=Button(root,text="Add",command=label_appear)
button.place(relx=0.5,y=250,anchor="center")

root.mainloop()
```

and here is the error that PyCharm throws:

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5sXP.png)

How can I change it so that it works as a real switch and not only as one time on/off button?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this question was asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580507/disable-enable-button-in-tkinter

Comment: It is not about changing the state of a button, it is about the broken function that cannot be executed after the second time the button is clicked

Comment: Replace `label.destroy()` by `label.place_forget()` inside `label_disappear()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have destroyed the label inside `label_disappear()`.  If you want the label to be shown again, replace `label.destroy()` by `label.place_forget()` inside `label_disappear()`:

```py
def label_disappear():
    global label
    global is_off

    label.place_forget()  # don't destroy the label, just make it invisible
    button.config(text="Add",command=label_appear)
    is_off=True
```